# How do I organize notifications on a Galaxy Note 10 - Seperate Messages from System Nots, Different Sounds, etc

Tags: notifications, lock-screens, notification-bar, notification-icons

Just switched from iPhone to my Note10 and i love it. However what drives me crazy is that I get tons of system notifications that all pool in the Notification bar. However, to be honest I only really want to see personal notifitaions there, like messages and so on, System Notifications better only if I request to see them. How do I seperate system notififications and message notifications. Also ho do I specify different sound, so I hear if its a Whatsapp or Insta or Facebook ...

Also, how do I make these notifications appear on the locked screen, like they do on the iphone?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to play around with the notification settings in your settings app. This is will be different for you, but on my Note 3 I go into the settings app -> Device -> Sounds and notifications -> application notifications. From here I can disable notifications for specific apps, and set apps as priority notifiers. imagine it's aomewhat similar with the note 10. Additionally, some apps will let you disable or change the notification sound from within the app, but here YMMV.

I'm not quite sure what you mean by separating system notifications and message notifications.

As for making them appear on the lock screen, see if you can find a related setting under notifications or lock screen. This is also under "sounds and notifications" in the note 3 settings app, although this is again likely to be different for you.